# kml + google maps api v3 + geoxml3

Tags: xml, google-maps-api-3, kml, polygons

I have one html file that load another kml file. Here is it:

http://mini.hr/stanonline/test.php

I would like to connect right menu "ODABERI KVART" with polygons on map, polygons are stored in kml. So when I choose something from menu the polygon change fill color and show infowindow.

Here is example how I would like to make it:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html

I was read about this and get information that must make xml file instead kml.
Can you help me to do something that would satisfy my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KML is XML.  The only reason a lot of my examples have the .xml extension is that until recently my server was not configured to serve KML files (files with the .kml extension).

working proof of concept using your KML through a proxy

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http://mini.hr/stanonline/mo_bck.kml

Since the above works, your server is configured to serve KML.

Comment: I mean for method `showAll()` is `map.fitBounds(geoXmlDoc.bounds);` how to set `map.fitBounds` to show my previous declared zoom `var zoom = 13;` ?

Comment: That isn't what map.fitBounds() does.  If you want to set the zoom to 13, set the zoom to 13 (map.setZoom(13);).

Comment: How can I set up method `kmlShowPlacemark(pm)` to show only the border of my polygon place without fill color or to remove polygon?

Comment: That is another question (really out of scope of this question, not a topic for discussion in the commments), perhaps you can post what have you tried, and where you ran into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I made something similarly u have on your website. U can check it on this link:

http://mini.hr/stanonline/test_mouseover.php

But if u can see that my zoom is not working bcs zoom is set to 13 and this one when u opet the page isn't it.

But if I add this in my address bar than zoom work:

```
?lat=45.345537&lng=14.439621&zoom=13&type=m&filename=mo_bck.kml
```

Example with redirect:

http://mini.hr/stanonline/test2.php

So how to fix the zoom problem without redirecting page?
And is it possible to throw ower the "show" link to infowindow of each polygon? If yes how?